# Order list corresponding to field in other list - Underscore Javascript

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I have two lists containing json structures. These structures have corresponding keys (not neccesarely same name) whose values are all present in both structures, unique and no duplicates.

`listA = [ {... title:'A' ...}, {... title:'B' ...}, {... title:'C' ...} ]`

`listB = [ {... name:'A' ...}, {... name:'C' ...}, {... name:'B' ...} ]`

But the orders are not the same. I want to reorder `listA` so that it corresponds to the order of `listB`.

`listA = [ {... title:'A' ...}, {... title:'C' ...}, {... title:'B' ...} ]`

How do I accomplish this with underscore?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a combination of [**sortBy**](http://underscorejs.org/#sortBy) and [**findIndex**](http://underscorejs.org/#findIndex):

```
var result = _.sortBy(lista, function(value){
    return _.findIndex(listb, { name: value.title });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

A brute force answer :)  Click "Run code snippet" below.

```js
var lista= [{title: 'one'}, {title: 'three'}, {title: 'two'}];
var listb= [{name: 'one'}, {name: 'two'}, {name: 'three'}];

function reorder(a,b) {
  return b.reduce(function(result, item) {
    result.push(_.find(a, function(ana) {
      return ana.title === item.name;
    }));
    return result;
  }, []);
}

document.body.appendChild(document.createTextNode(JSON.stringify(reorder(lista, listb))));
```

```html
<script src="http://underscorejs.org/underscore-min.js"></script>
<body>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

The elements of `listB` can be nicely identified by something that is a valid object key so I'd do it in two steps:

1. Build a map of `name` to index from `listB`.
2. Sort `listA` using that map.

That could look like this:

```
var indexes = _(listB).reduce(function(m, e, i) {
    m[e.name] = i;
    return m;
}, { });
var sorted = _(listA).sortBy(function(e) { return indexes[e.title] });
```

This lets you make only one pass through `listB` rather than searching it over and over again.

```js
var listA = [
    { title: 'A' },
    { title: 'B' },
    { title: 'C' }
];
var listB = [
    { name: 'A' },
    { name: 'C' },
    { name: 'B' }
];

var indexes = _(listB).reduce(function(m, e, i) {
    m[e.name] = i;
    return m;
}, { });

var sorted = _(listA).sortBy(function(e) { return indexes[e.title] });
console.log(sorted);
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>
```